# Grails getProperties method does not always return properties in the correct order

Tags: json, grails, groovy, flexigrid

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
    name
    description

    static constraints = {
        name()
        description()
    }
}
```

I want to add display instances of my class in a [Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/).  When data is sent to a flexigrid it needs to be in a format like JSON or XML... I have chosen JSON.  Flexigrid expects JSON arrays it receives to have the following format:

```
{
    "page": "1",
    "total": "1",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "cell": [
                "1",
                "The name of Foo 1",
                "The description of Foo 1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "cell": [
                "2",
                "The name of Foo 2",
                "The description of Foo 2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To get my `Foo` objects into this format I do something similar to this:

```
def foos = Foo.getAll( 1, 2 )

def results = [:]
results[ "page" ] = params.page
results[ "total" ] = foos.size()
results[ "rows" ] = []

for( foo in foos ) {
    def cell = []
    cell.add( foo.id )

    foo.getProperties().each() { key, value -> // Sometimes get foo.getProperties().each() returns foo.description then foo.name instead of foo.name then foo.description as desired.
        cell.add( value.toString() )
    }

    results[ "rows" ].add( [ "id": foo.id, "cell": cell ] )
}

render results as JSON
```

The problem is that every once in a while `foo.getProperties().each()` returns `foo.description` then `foo.name` resulting in `foo.description` being put in the name column of my flexigrid and `foo.name` being put in the description column of my flexigrid for a specific row.

I tried specifying constraints in the `Foo` domain class so the `getProperties` would return in the correct order, but it didn't work.  **How can I make sure `getProperties` returns properties in a predictable order?**

**This is how I fixed this issuse:**

```
def items = Foo.getAll()

for( item in items ) {
    def cell = []
    cell.add( item.id )
    Foo.constraints.each() { key, value ->
        def itemValue = item.getProperty( key )
        if( !( itemValue instanceof Collection ) ) {
            cell.add( itemValue.toString() )
        }
    }
}
```

So `Foo.constraints` gets a map of constraints where each constraint is an instance of `Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$UnmodifiableEntry`.  After testing I have found this map always returns my `Foo` static constraints in the order I entered them (also confirmed by Ian).  Now only the properties of the `item` which are in `Foo.constraints` will be added to the `cell` for flexigrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `foo.getProperties()` guarantees anything about the ordering.  But `Foo.constraints` is overridden at runtime to return not the original closure, but a `Map` of `ConstrainedProperty` objects and the keys in this map *are* guaranteed to be in the same order as the constraints closure (this is how scaffolding is able to use the constraints ordering to define the order in which fields are presented in the scaffolded views).  So you could do something like

```
def props = [:] // [:] declares a LinkedHashMap, so order-preserving
Foo.constraints.each { k, v ->
  props[k] = foo."${k}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo.getProperties().sort()` or if there's no good way to sort the properties in the order you need, you could always define the order of the properties yourself in a list to iterate over.

```
def properties = ['name', 'description']
properties.each {
     cell.add(foo."$it")
}
```

Comment: I would like to be able to sort the properties in the order which I have specified they should be listed in the domain class constraints.  Calling Foo.constraints returns an instance of  `Collections$UnmodifiableMap$UnmodifiableEntrySet$UnmodifiableEntry` but I don't know if those entries will always be in the order I have specified in the domain class.