# Get Grails domain persistent properties in order

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

Is there some way to retrieve the persistent properties of a Domain Class in the same order I declared them in the class?

```
class MyDomainClass {
  String prop1
  String prop2
  String prop3
}


def domainClass = grailsApplication.getDomainClass(MyDomainClass)
def props = domainClass.persistentProperties //this not retrieve them in order.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150476/grails-getproperties-method-does-not-always-return-properties-in-the-correct-ord

Comment: @doelleri I didn't see that in the related questions :) That's an interesting approach, but fields not declared in constraints are required by default, so this breaks the point of using `grails.gorm.default.constraints`. If there's no other way, it's a price to pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class::[getDeclaredFields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) does the job. Once it is compiled by the oracle's javac 7 and run by oracle's jvm 7 you will get the result, but I don't think you are guaranteed to get it tomorrow:

> *"The elements in the array returned are not sorted and are not in any
>   particular order".*

```
class MyDomainClass {
  String name
  String hobby
  int age
}
MyDomainClass.class.getDeclaredFields().each { println it.name }
```

Output:

```
name
hobby
age
$staticClassInfo
__$stMC
```

Anyway that's all not too good. One could use annotations supplying the ordering information.

Comment: Since you pointed that it may be not sorted, I think that the constraints approach is better than that, since it allows the dev to set the order. The only con is the developer remember to set all fields. For that I will add the not declared in the final of the list. Thanks for answering!